# React native Lightbox is not zooming

Tags: react-native, lightbox, lightbox2

I'm covering my Images with lightbox to show up in fullscreen. It does not gives error on android but when I open it in lightbox image is still same.

Imports

```
import { TouchableOpacity, Image} from 'react-native';
import Lightbox from 'react-native-lightbox-v2';
//also tryed import Lightbox from 'react-native-lightbox';
```

in render

```
<Lightbox>
                <Image
                  source={{uri: this.props.mediaUrl}}
                  style={{
                    width: 300,
                    height: 150,
                    resizeMode: 'cover', 
                    borderRadius: 18,
                    marginHorizontal:20,alignItems:'center'
                  }}
                />
 </Lightbox>
```

Result

[In render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nylop.png)

[Onpress in Lightbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QOpW.png)

What should I change. Thank you

Comment: Exept me Lightbox works correct perfectly right

Comment: I solved it with using  https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-modal